Anyone familiar with CUDA IPC in Python with ctypes?
I'm currently trying to communicate large data between processes inside and outside a container via the GPU. I'm using CUDA IPC, and while the sender uploads the data, the receiver reads only zeros. The device IDs and memory handles are the same on both sides, so I'm wondering why this might be happening. Any ideas?
## loading cpu to gpu
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import cv2



cuda_lib = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\cudart64_12.dll")

# Check current CUDA device
device_id = ctypes.c_int()
status = cuda_lib.cudaGetDevice(ctypes.byref(device_id))
if status != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"cudaGetDevice failed with error code: {status}")
print(f"Current CUDA Device ID: {device_id.value}")


message = "hello, world"
message_bytes = message.encode('utf-8')  
message_length = len(message_bytes)


d_array = ctypes.c_void_p()
cuda_lib.cudaMalloc(ctypes.byref(d_array), message_length)

cuda_lib.cudaMemset(d_array, 0, message_length)

print(f"message_bytes:{message_bytes}")

binary_representation = ' '.join(format(byte, '08b') for byte in message_bytes)

print(f"Binary representation: {binary_representation}")


status = cuda_lib.cudaMemcpy(
    d_array,
    message_bytes,
    message_length,
    1  # cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
)

if status != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"cudaMemcpy failed with error code: {status}")


mem_handle = ctypes.create_string_buffer(64)
cuda_lib.cudaIpcGetMemHandle(ctypes.byref(mem_handle), d_array)


with open("ipc_handle.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(mem_handle.raw)
    f.write(message_length.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')) 

with open("ipc_handle.bin", "rb") as f:
    mem_handle = f.read(64) 
    message_length_bytes = f.read(4)  
    message_length = int.from_bytes(message_length_bytes, byteorder='little') 


print(f"Memory Handle: {mem_handle.hex()}")  
print(f"Message Length: {message_length}")  

print("Data has been copied to GPU and memory handle has been saved.")



## receiver
import ctypes
import numpy as np


cuda_lib = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin\cudart64_12.dll")


# Check current CUDA device
device_id = ctypes.c_int()
status = cuda_lib.cudaGetDevice(ctypes.byref(device_id))
if status != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"cudaGetDevice failed with error code: {status}")
print(f"Current CUDA Device ID: {device_id.value}")


with open("ipc_handle.bin", "rb") as f:
    mem_handle = f.read(64)
    message_length_bytes = f.read(4)  
    message_length = ctypes.c_int.from_buffer_copy(message_length_bytes).value 


print(f"Memory Handle: {mem_handle.hex()}")  
print(f"Message Length: {message_length}")

d_array = ctypes.c_void_p()
cuda_lib.cudaIpcOpenMemHandle(ctypes.byref(d_array), mem_handle, 1)


result_array = ctypes.create_string_buffer(message_length)


status = cuda_lib.cudaMemcpy(
    result_array,
    d_array,
    ctypes.c_size_t(message_length),
    2  # cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost
)
print(result_array.raw) 
print(len(result_array))
if status != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(f"cudaMemcpy failed with error code: {status}")


print(f'result_array:{result_array}')  # 바이트 배열을 문자열로 변환하여 출력
print(type(result_array))

binary_representation = ' '.join(format(ord(result_array[i]), '08b') for i in range(message_length))
print(f"Binary representation of result_array: {binary_representation}")

cuda_lib.cudaFree(d_array)


results are as follows
Sender ->
Current CUDA Device ID: 0
message_bytes:b'hello, world'
Binary representation: 01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00101100 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100
Memory Handle: 301457b23902000094120000000000000c000000000000000002000000000000000100000000000021000000000000007c05000000000000c002004000000000
Message Length: 12
Data has been copied to GPU and memory handle has been saved.
Receiver ->
Current CUDA Device ID: 0
Memory Handle: 301457b23902000094120000000000000c000000000000000002000000000000000100000000000021000000000000007c05000000000000c002004000000000
Message Length: 12
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
12
result_array:<ctypes.c_char_Array_12 object at 0x000001E4CA8E3BC0>
<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_12'>
Binary representation of result_array: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Binary representation before and after loading have to be same but only 0 values are received

I don't have the libraries to reproduce the problem, but the typical issue is not explicitly declaring .argtypes and .restype for the ctypes functions called.
